# Please help in identifying Gender of budgies

Tags: birds, gender-differentiation, budgerigar

I have below pair of budgies. I think the white one is male and yellow one is female, however I want a confirmation.

Please help in identifying the gender.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The dark yellow one is a female - note the brown above the beak (cere).

The other budgie, the pale yellow (I don't see it as white) is likely a young male with the purple cere, that will turn blue as he matures.

They are very cute, enjoy!

Some links:

https://pethelpful.com/birds/Is-My-Budgie-A-Boy-Or-A-Girl

[image]

https://m.wikihow.com/Identify-Your-Budgie%27s-Sex

> Consider the age of your budgie. If your budgie is less than 4 months
> old, it will have immature colors respective to their sex. Before
> this time, the colored area that shows sex will be pink or purple on a
> male and white or pale blue on a female. If your budgie hasn't had its
> first molt, has dark button eyes, and has bars coming from its head to
> cere, then it's less than four months old.
>
> - If your budgie is
>   immature or less than 4 months old, the cere on males will slowly turn
>   deep blue and females will keep white or pale blue before showing tan.