# Please help in identify budgie gender

Tags: budgerigar

Pls help me in identify my new budgies gender[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please help in identifying Gender of budgies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26696/please-help-in-identifying-gender-of-budgies)

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please see the linked question for an answer to a very similar question. IF THIS does not answer your question, let us know in a comment and tell what is different in your case. If you do not, we assume your question solved and it will be closed.